# what are the frameworks / wrapper libraries written in clojurescript

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, clojurescript

I have just started with clojurescript. The first thing I noticed is having multiple wrapper libraries around React. I didn't find any rich alternatives like we have in Javascript(Choices like backbone, ember, angular etc). Seems like CLJS community naturally leans towards React as both favors immutable data structures.

We can definitely import foreign libraries but they don't fit in naturally as they tend to use JS data structures than CLJS ones.

So if one would like to start adventures without React wrappers what choices would one have?

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be answerable on StackOverflow. If you have a favorite framework you want to use with clojurescript and ask a specific question about that you'll have more chance of a good answer. Having said that: I do think it will be quite hard to combine clojurescript with the bigger js frameworks and make it feel natural for precisely the reasons you mention yourself.

Comment: Well, I don't have any favorite framework as such. I'm just exploring the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think most CLJS frameworks build on React because it **does one job** well: managing *reactive updates of the DOM*. When data (i.e., *props* of a component) changes, React can be used just to render the view, whereas managing data (i.e., state) of the application remains a separate concern. State management is where ClojureScript frameworks (e.g., [Om Next](https://github.com/omcljs/om), [Re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame)) start to differ more from each other. (Note that *route* is just a piece of data as well, although many frameworks handle it like a special kind of thing.)

So, one reason why React is popular in the CLJS community is that it favours a modular architecture. Further, React documentation encourages a functional programming style, where most of the components are written as *pure* functions. React does also play well with immutable data, although you need special trickery (e.g., [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)) to enforce it in JavaScript.

This being said, it is certainly possible to use the bigger monolithic frameworks from ClojureScript (see [POC Angular 2 site here](http://deliberate-software.com/cljs-angular2/)), but it can be quite cumbersome. At the lowest level, you can use direct JavaScript interop (see [CLJS cheatsheet](http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/)), to manipulate DOM directly:

```
(-> js/document
  (.getElementById "app")
  (.-innerHTML)
  (set! "CLJS rocks!")
```

Comment: I agree. Cljs is pretty good at managing data and React just deals with dom mutations. But what if someone don't want to use React because of licensing issues. There aren't any alternatives.
As I mentioned earlier if we try to use any other JS frameworks they don't fit in. 
I'm interested in knowing if there are any efforts already put into developing a framework in cljs which may just abstracts _view_ layer (like om without React) or a new one altogether.

Comment: I just found [Enfocus](http://ckirkendall.github.io/enfocus-site/) by googling "Enlive CLJS". The docs on [view binding](http://ckirkendall.github.io/enfocus-site/index.html#view-binding) describe reactive UI updates when the state changes.

Comment: Interesting. I will explore. Thank you.